# When implementing my api, I'd like for it be view able in xml format. Not just JSON

Tags: python, django, xml, django-rest-framework

I'm creating a web api for the polling app Django gives us as practice for myself. I was able to go pretty far, but I am stuck with wanting to give an option for formatting with xml.

I tried using `DEFAULT_PARSER` and `DEFAULT_RENDER` and it didn't really workout the way I wanted it to. I just want to give an option like I have for JSON on there.

This is my api/views class

```
from rest_framework import generics
from . serializers import QuestionSerializer, ChoiceSerializer
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from rest_framework.filters import OrderingFilter, SearchFilter

from polls.models import Choice, Question

class QuestionList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer
    queryset = Question.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter, SearchFilter)
    filter_fields = {'id': ['gte', 'lte', 'exact'], 'pub_date': ['gte', 'lte']}
    ordering_fields = ('id', 'question_text', 'pub_date')
    search_fields = ('pub_date', 'question_text')


class ChoiceList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ChoiceSerializer
    queryset = Choice.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter, SearchFilter)
    # trying to do greater than or less than filter fields stuff
    filter_fields = {'id': ['gte', 'lte', 'exact'], 'votes': ['gte', 'lte', 'exact']}
    ordering_fields = ('id', 'votes', 'choice_text', 'question',)
    search_fields = ('choice_text', 'question')
```

this is api/serializers class

```
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets
from polls.models import Question, Choice


#  serializer is the way you can see the list of info for the models you have selected

class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = '__all__'

# i have no idea how to make hyperlinks to open up another page
class ChoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = ('id', 'votes', 'choice_text', 'question')
```

[Want to be able to have a drop down menu and have it say 'XML'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SvvG.png)

Comment: "I tried using DEFAULT_PARSER and DEFAULT_RENDER and it didn't really workout the way I wanted it to." could you elaborate ? My initial answer would be: "use parser / renderer"

Comment: I put DEFAULT_PARSER and DEFAULT_RENDER into my setting.py file and then when I loaded up the api everything was and xml form. I just want it to be an option like JSON. Similar to the picture I have posted, i want to get a drop down menu thaty has "XML" when you click on "GET". Hope that clears things up

Comment: What did you set the `DEFAULT_PARSER` & `DEFAULT_RENDERER` to ?

Comment: i did:

    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
         'rest_framework_xml.parsers.XMLParser',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_xml.renderers.XMLRenderer',
    )

Comment: Show your REST_FRAMEWORK config

Comment: REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    #'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (,
        #'rest_framework_xml.parsers.XMLParser',
    #),
    #'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        #'rest_framework_xml.renderers.XMLRenderer',
    #),
    'DEFAULT_MODEL_SERIALIZER_CLASS':
        'rest_framework.serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer',
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the XML parser/renderer to the default ones:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
        'rest_framework_xml.renderers.XMLRenderer'
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
        'rest_framework_xml.parsers.XMLParser'
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! got it work. I didn't have BrowsableAPIRender and FormParser. Thank you!!!